# gcc - unknown switches (absent also from the manpage)

Tags: compiling, gcc, dynamic-linking

I'm trying to experiment with shared objects and found the below snippet on http://www.gambas-it.org/wiki/index.php?title=Creare_una_Libreria_condivisa_(Shared_Library)_.so

```
gcc -g -shared -Wl,-soname,libprimo.so.0 -o libprimo.so.0.0 primo.o -lc
```

I browsed trough the manpages and online, but I didn't find what the `-lc` switch does, can someone tell me?

Comment: the short answer is that in this case that option does nothing, because `-lc` (link to libc) will be added automatically by gcc's specs (unless `-nodefaullibs` or `-nostdlib` was used), as you can easily see by ommitting it and adding the `-v` option to gcc.

Comment: ... and adding it yourself can mess things up, because there may be things (like `crtend.o` or `libgcc.a`) that need to be linked after all normal libraries but _before_ the core C library.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The option is shown as "`-l_library_`" (no space) or "`-l _library_`" (with a space) and `c` is the *library* argument,
see https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc

`-lc` will link `libc` (`-lfoobar` would link `libfoobar` etc.)

**General information about options and arguments**

UNIX commands often accept option arguments with or without whitespace. If you have an option `o` which takes an argument `arg` you can write `-o arg` or `-oarg`. On the other hand you can combine options that don't take an argument, e.g. `-a -b -c` or `-abc`.
When you see `-lc` you can only find out from the documentation (man page) if this is the combination of options `-l` and `-c` or option `-l` with argument `c` or a single option `-lc`.

See also https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html

**Note:** `gcc` is an exception from this general concept. You cannot combine options for `gcc`.

Comment: Thank you, the fact there wasn't a space led me to confusion.

Comment: You cannot combine options with `cc`, even if they don't take any argument (you cannot write `cc -cg` instead of `cc -c -g`.

Answer (score 8):

`-lc` links with `libc`, the C library.

See the description of `-l`*`library`* in [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options).